# Wicket: Using a editable Inline-label inside a ListView and update a model after change this label value

Tags: java, scala, wicket

I need to use a editable label or inline-label in a ListView and after change the
value of this component I want to know how can I update the property of
the Object displayed in this listView

```
add(new ListView[SomeObject]("listSomeObject", listData) {

    override protected def onBeforeRender() {
     ...
      super.onBeforeRender()
    }

    def populateItem(item: ListItem[SomeObject]) = {
      var objValue = item.getModelObject()

      item.add(new Label("total", objValue.toString(getFormatter())))
     }
    }
  })
```

In the code above, the object SomeObject has a property called total, the listView
shows a set of SomeObject, when the label total is changed in some line of the
listview the corresponding object SomeObject should be updated with the new
value of the label total.

Someone can provide some useful example for help me with this task?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use a model to display your property. For example a propertyModel. The method `getObject()` will get called on display. A PropertyModel will call the getter for the selected property. You can have your object have a getter that retrieves the formatted value that you are interested in.

```
item.add(new Label("total", new PropertyModel(item.getModel(), "formattedValue")))
```